# Nominal or Ordinal Examples

Tags: database, statistics, spss, categorical-data, ordinals

I have some ordinal and nominal examples for SPSS and am not sure whether I have done it right.

- Ordinal is where order is important e.g. Height: 1 is 150cm-159cm, 2 is 160cm-169cm, 3 is 170cm-179cm, 4 is 180cm-189cm
- Another ordinal example: 1 is high, 2 is medium and 3 is low
- Nominal is where order doesn't matter e.g. 1 is vegetables, 2 is fruit, 3 is dairy, 4 is confectionery

Comment: OK???? what is the question?

Comment: Hi John, I have data sets in an Assignment similar to these and I need to import them to SPSS correctly

Comment: Are you asking (a) "How to import these to SPSS correctly?"; (b) "Are my data sets correct?" or (c) Something else ?

Comment: I would like to please know if I have correctly described the variable type as nominal and ordinal. I know how to import. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are fine except that they leave out the third case - scale variables.  Your first example might be treated as scale.  You might find it useful to read Ruben van den Berg's recent article on measurement levels at https://www.spss-tutorials.com/  (Look for the measurement level tutorial).

However, in most cases Statistics does not actively use measurement levels except for categorical vs continuous/scale in a few cases.  TREES is an exception.  It is up to the analyst to use the appropriate techniques.  Statistics will guess the measurement level when data are read, but these are only guesses.

Comment: Thank you for this - it was very helpful. I think I should be entering height as a scale variable because it has fixed units of measurement between factor levels, but I think if it is instead: 1 is <159cm, 2 is 160cm-169cm, 3 is 170cm-179cm, 4 >180cm than it would probably be ordinal? Thanks